# Arint System.Drawing.Graphics suppose to write/modify the image its attached to?

Tags: vb.net, graphics

As you use a graphics object shouldn't the changes occur on the bitmap (source image) at some point? Running the code below I get 5 images that are all identical to the source. 1.bmp, 2.bmp, 3.bmp, 4.bmp, and 5.bmp are identical to "scaleCharacter" except 4 & 5 have higher compression (smaller file size)

```
Private Function DrawCharacterMenu() As Boolean

    Try
        'Background
        Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(100, 100, 128, 128)
        Graphics.FromImage(Render).FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, rect)

        'Scale up sprite
        Dim scaleCharacter As Bitmap = ActiveCharacter.img.Clone
        Using grDest = Graphics.FromImage(scaleCharacter)
            scaleCharacter.Save("1.bmp")
            grDest.ScaleTransform(4.0F, 4.0F)
            scaleCharacter.Save("2.bmp")
            grDest.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
            scaleCharacter.Save("3.bmp")
            grDest.DrawImage(scaleCharacter, 0, 0)
            scaleCharacter.Save("4.bmp")
        End Using
        scaleCharacter.Save("5.bmp")

        'Draw scaled up sprite to rendering
        Graphics.FromImage(Render).DrawImage(scaleCharacter, 100, 100)

    Catch ex As Exception
        addDebugMessage("Error: Mainmenu.DrawCharacterMenu: " & ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try

    Return True
End Function
```

I would Expect 1 to be the same as 'scaleCharacter'

2 and beyond to be 4 times larger (32x32 to 128x128)

3 and beyond to have less interpolation (not looked stretched)

The finished 'scaleCharacter' drawn onto the rendering also is identical to the original image...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your images are the same because technically you never change them.

1. [`Graphics.ScaleTransform()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.scaletransform?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Graphics_ScaleTransform_System_Single_System_Single_) changes only the internal "world" matrix used when drawing primitives. `ScaleTransform(4.0F, 4.0F)` makes the *drawing grid* 4x wider and 4x taller, ***but it doesn't change the image itself*** until you draw something on it. For instance, if you were to draw a 20 x 10 rectangle on your image now it would result in a rectangle 80 x 40 in size.

   To resize the actual image you have to create a new bitmap with the scaled size, then draw the old image scaled onto it.
2. Changing `Graphics.InterpolationMode` affects only *newly* drawn objects. Again it doesn't change your image until you draw something on it.
3. Finally, while `grDest.DrawImage(scaleCharacter, 0, 0)` does change your image, it draws the same image in the top-left corner (0, 0) of itself, so there is no *visible* change.

Here's how you can make it work:

**Scaling your image:**

```
'Scale factor.
Dim scaleFactor As Single = 4.0F

'Create a new bitmap of the scaled size.
Using scaledBmp As New Bitmap(scaleCharacter.Width * scaleFactor, scaleCharacter.Height * scaleFactor)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(scaledBmp)
        'Draw the old image, scaled, onto the new one.
        'srcRect:  The rectangle specifying which portion of the source image (scaleCharacter) to draw.
        '          We want the full image so we specify (0, 0, source width, source height).
        'destRect: The rectangle specifying where on the destination image (scaledBmp) to draw the source image.
        '          Since we want to scale it we specify the full destination image (0, 0, dest width, dest height).
        Dim srcRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, scaleCharacter.Width, scaleCharacter.Height)
        Dim destRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, scaledBmp.Width, scaledBmp.Height)
        g.DrawImage(scaleCharacter, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

        'Save the image.
        scaledBmp.Save("2.bmp")
    End Using
End Using
```

**Scaling your image using Nearest Neighbour interpolation:**

```
'Create a new bitmap of the scaled size.
Using scaledBmp As New Bitmap(scaleCharacter.Width * scaleFactor, scaleCharacter.Height * scaleFactor)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(scaledBmp)
        'Set the interpolation mode before drawing.
        g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor

        'Draw the old image, scaled, onto the new one.
        'srcRect:  The rectangle specifying which portion of the source image (scaleCharacter) to draw.
        '          We want the full image so we specify (0, 0, source width, source height).
        'destRect: The rectangle specifying where on the destination image (scaledBmp) to draw the source image.
        '          Since we want to scale it we specify the full destination image (0, 0, dest width, dest height).
        Dim srcRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, scaleCharacter.Width, scaleCharacter.Height)
        Dim destRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, scaledBmp.Width, scaledBmp.Height)
        g.DrawImage(scaleCharacter, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

        'Save the image.
        scaledBmp.Save("3.bmp")
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I have a question and was wondering you might be able to help ?

Comment: @zackraiyan : Perhaps... [Let us continue this discussion in chat.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185914/discussion-between-visual-vincent-and-zack-raiyan)

Comment: Can you clarify why this code has worked for me in another area;         <code>Try
            Rendering = MyMap.map

            Graphics.FromImage(Rendering).ScaleTransform(SizeMultiplyer, SizeMultiplyer)
            Graphics.FromImage(Rendering).InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
            Graphics.FromImage(Rendering).DrawImage(Rendering, 0, 0)

            PictureBox1.Image = Rendering
        Catch ex As Exception...'  Is it because i'm using a picturebox paint? (P.s sorry I cant get code tags to work)

Comment: @Will.N : That can't possibly work as you are creating three different and independent `Graphics` objects which, by the way, you never dispose of. That code will memory leak like crazy. Are you sure that it isn't just your [`PictureBox.SizeMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode?view=netframework-4.7.2) that stretches the image? Try saving the bitmap and see the result.

Comment: @Will.N : By the way `inline code` in comments can be formatted by surrounding it with backticks ( \` ) like so: \`this is code\` - which results in: `this is code`. Though multiline code doesn't look good in comments, so it's usually better to edit that into your question or use a service like https://pastebin.com/. You can find out more in the [Markdown and Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). :)

Comment: Yep your right there was code elsewhere doing the actual scaling. I tricked myself into a false understanding lol. thanks very much for the help I properly understand this now.

Comment: @Will.N : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project, and Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)